# Double Scrollbar Appearing

Tags: css, iframe, scroll

I have a double scrollbar appearing in some of the pages on my site. I've tried to set the html and body to overflow:hidden (with !important;) to no avail.

I'm using Chrome and the pages the double scroll appears is on my "about" page and on my "newsroom" page. Yesterday, the scrollbar was visible only on my "contact us" page but seems to have moved over to populate other pages -_-

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My site: http://tempwp.ttcbd.com/

Comment: I'm not seeing a double scroll bar, I'm on Chrome.

Comment: That's strange... I've cleared my browser cache and it will not go away for me.